# How to make one table record editable on button click in React when the table record is mapped?

Tags: reactjs

My question is How to make one table record editable like the picture shows on the bottom when the table rows are got from list mapping?

```
<tbody>
          {
          this.state.languageList.map((list, index) =>
            <TableElement key={index} item={list} />
             )
          }
          </tbody>
```

In the TableElement.jsx.

```
render() {
    const { language, languageLevel, personLanguageId } = this.props.item;
    return (
        <tr key={personLanguageId}>
            <td>
                <div>
                    {language}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    {languageLevel}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i className="pencil alternate icon" />
                <i className="trash icon" onClick={() => this.delete(personLanguageId)} />
            </td>
        </tr>

    );
}
```

[image: How the table looks]

Comment: What specifically are you having a problem with? Determining which item to make editable? Actually showing the controls to edit? Controlling the edit values?

Comment: How did you achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the information which item is selected in the parent component, and pass this information to the item:

```
this.state.languageList.map((list, index) =>
    <TableElement
        key={index}
        item={list}
        isSelected={ list.personLanguageId === this.state.selectedId }
        onSelect={ ( id )=>{ this.setState({ selectedId: id }); } }
    />
)
```

and inside the item:

```
<tr onClick={ ()=>{ this.props.onSelect( personLanguageId ) } }>
    { !this.props.isSelected ? null :
        <td>
            <i onClick={() => this.delete(personLanguageId)} />
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```